# Check if row in dataframe exists in another dataframe and remove from both

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to check if row(s) in one dataframe exist in another and if so I want to remove them from both dataframes. So far all the examples I am seeing use pd.merge but that merges into one dataframe. My goal is to retain two separate dataframes and just remove the common rows.

The example is as follows:

```
df1:
                id            name             class        Grade
0             2547            John             Math         119.01
1             2547            Joe              Science      0.00
2             2547            Steve            History      0.47
3             2547            Hari             PE           5.70

df2:
                id            name             class        Grade
0             2547            John             Math         119.01
1             2547            Joe              Science      2
2             2547            Steve            History      22
3             2547            Hari             PE           5.71

expected output:

    df1:
                    id            name             class        Grade
    0             2547            Joe              Science      0.00
    1             2547            Steve            History      0.47
    2             2547            Hari             PE           5.70
    
    df2:
                    id            name             class        Grade
    0             2547            Joe              Science      2
    1             2547            Steve            History      22
    2             2547            Hari             PE           5.71
```

so far what I've tried is as follows but this is not helpful because it merges the two dataframes:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Grade'], how='outer')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store the common rows with an `inner` merge, append that to both dataframes, and drop duplicates without keeping any of the duplicates, `drop_duplicates(keep=False)`:

```
t = df1.merge(df2,'inner')
df2, df1 = df2.append(t).drop_duplicates(keep=False) , df1.append(t).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Prints:

```
>>> df1
 
     id   name    class  Grade
1  2547    Joe  Science   0.00
2  2547  Steve  History   0.47
3  2547   Hari       PE   5.70

>>> df2

     id   name    class  Grade
1  2547    Joe  Science   2.00
2  2547  Steve  History  22.00
3  2547   Hari       PE   5.71

>>> t
 
     id  name class   Grade
0  2547  John  Math  119.01
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df3 = df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)]
df4 = df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(axis=1)]
df1 = df3
df2 = df4
```

Or just,

```
df1, df2 = df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)], df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultiIndex` objects using the `from_frame` method, then check for the membership using `MultiIndex.isin` to create  boolean masks in order to filter the rows

```
i1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)
i2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2)

df1, df2 = df1[~i1.isin(i2)], df2[~i2.isin(i1)]
```

---

```
>>> df1
     id   name    class  Grade
1  2547    Joe  Science   0.00
2  2547  Steve  History   0.47
3  2547   Hari       PE   5.70

>>> df2
     id   name    class  Grade
1  2547    Joe  Science   2.00
2  2547  Steve  History  22.00
3  2547   Hari       PE   5.71
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try this -



 dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"column1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
    
    dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"column1": [1, 2]})
    
    
    common = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, on=["column1"])
    
    result = dataframe1[~dataframe1.column1.isin(common.column1)]
    
    
    print(result)
```

Refer this article for more details-
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-are-not-in-another-dataframe-in-python

or you could you this just to check-

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='grade', suffixes=(' from df1',' from df2'))
df.insert(0, 'id', df['grade'] + '-' + df.pop('grade'))
print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This doesn't help because I get a result dataframe whereas my goal is to just remove the common rows from dataframe1 and dataframe2.. if that makes sense